# DVR error: kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, h.264, embedded-linux, dvr, cctv

My DVR is connected to internet but when ssh, the error is kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer. It is port 22 and I cannot access the Linux terminal. The system cannot be accessed by command line as it has no function and fixes require cli access which the DVR can't due to ssh error. Client is Zmodo H.264 DVR zmd-dt-sfn6. Is there any fix please?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngrok kex\_exchange\_identification: read: Connection reset by peer](https://superuser.com/questions/1584881/ngrok-kex-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: This id different as this device has no cli interface and ssh has an issue